# Material UI hide element onClick or when checkbox is checked

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to hide element when button is clicked or when checkbox is checked. I tried to Google the solution but can't find anything. Can anyone help with this?

I want to hide that first MenuItem which has Input inside of it and it needs to be hidden when Button is clicked which is inside of second MenuItem **or** Checkbox is checked which is inside of third MenuItem. Also it needs to return back to normal when clicking Button again, or when checkbox is not checked.

```
<MenuItem>
    <Input />
<MenuItem/>
<MenuItem>
    <Button onClick={handleClick}>
        Hide onClick!
    </Button
</MenuItem
<MenuItem>
    <Checkbox />
</MenuItem>
```

I assume I need to do something like this. Inside handleClick I need to set input MenuItems display to none.

```
const [hide, setHide] = useState(false);

const handleClick = () => {
   
}
```

So basically I think I need to change style of element onClick or checked. I don't have much to show because I don't have any clue how to do that.

Comment: do all these `MenuItem` is under one `Select` or under different `Select`?

Comment: All of these MenuItems are inside of same Modal. I could use also Boxes but MenuItems was perfect sized. I can change those also to Boxes if it affects to solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the conditional rendering for this.

```
{hide && (
  <MenuItem>
    <Input />
  </MenuItem>
)}
```

now, whenever the `hide` state is true, `<Input/>` menuItem will be rendered and for false, it'll be hidden.
To mutate the `hide` state from both `CheckBox` and `Button`, create a handler that will set the state.

```
const toggleHide = () => {
  setHide((oldState) => !oldState);
};
```

Now call this `toggleHide` function on the click of the `Button` and onChange of the `Checkbox`.
*Note:- for better result onClick listeners can be added to the `MenuItem` instead of the `Button` and `CheckBox`.*

[image: Edit tender-hamilton-x041s]

Comment: Actually I need also modify a bit of styling aswell. Do you have some additional line which adds some styling or overrides some styling?

Comment: styling of what? `MenuItem` ?

Comment: Yes, example when clicking button it overrides button default width to be a bit wider

Comment: well, for this you can use the classnames conditionally. `className={hide?classes.styleOnHidden:classes.styleOnVisible}`, and given the styles to the `styleOnVisible` and `styleOnHidden` accordingly

Answer (score 2):

change this

```
<MenuItem>
<Input />
<MenuItem/>
```

to this

```
{ hide && (<MenuItem>
<Input />
<MenuItem/>) }
```

and the function must be like this

```
const handleClick = () => {
 setHide(prev => !prev)

 }
```

Comment: I also tried this solution and this is pretty decent solution aswell, thanks!